# C++ formatting in netbeans for multi-conditional if statements

Tags: c++, netbeans

I want to create a format for my code. But netbeans is not allowing to do it. I've changed the settings in `Tools`->`Options`->`Editor`->`Formatting`, but I'm not getting expected result.

I'm getting this when I click formatting:

[image]

This is what I'm expecting the result to be:

[image]

Pay attention to the position of ")". If its needed to make changes in pluging source code I can do it, but I don't know where to look for this.

Comment: I don't see any difference in position of ')'

Comment: Sorry was rush to train. Will fix when return. In real autoformat ad additional tab before ")"

Comment: Have fixed question. Thank for reply

Answer (score 1):

Download below plugin and use formatter

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38688/jindent-source-code-formatter-for-java-c-c

Comment: Thanks for help but I can't make this work http://prnt.sc/c5iczq It alwais make one line

Comment: Hi, friend i dont know about that i just try to help,if you find answer then update my answer

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help. I'll add image if some else will read this. Here base code http://prnt.sc/c5ierj and it return http://prnt.sc/c5iewl. The same result you'll got if put settings to after. Pay attantion to if

Answer (score 1):

Use `Alt` + `Shift` + `F` to format your code in Netbeans.

This command will format the entire file, however, if you just want to format a specific block of code, then select those lines and then use this command.

Comment: I know it. But it not what I make questions. It will help if you are coding. But if you get source and want to format then you need make many selection for each file